# making route from places in one go

Tags: javascript, maps

let's say i have 5 places(A, B, C, D, E). and i want to make route from A -> B -> C -> D ->E. is it possible to make a route like that in one go `directionsService.route()` *callback*. sorry for my english :(

```
      function buatRute(){
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(document.getElementById('map'));
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();  

      var request = {
          origin: {lat: start.getPosition().lat(), lng: start.getPosition().lng()},
          destination: {lat: end.getPosition().lat(), lng: end.getPosition().lng()},
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      alert(start.getPosition().lat());
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
         if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
             directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

         } 
      });

  }
```